# sign in VS sign up | devise with omniauth-facebook

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, oauth-2.0, facebook-authentication, omniauth-facebook

- Rails 5.0.0.1
- Ruby 2.3.1p112
- gem 'devise'
- gem 'omniauth'
- gem 'omniauth-facebook'

I have a app working with omniauth-facebook and Devise which must have some required extra attributes on signup page. It works very well but I'm having some difficulty on breaking authentication into two situations/behaviours:

1. The specific page for user sign up by requiring some extra params.
2. The specific page for user sign in (if the user already signed up).

The problem is on first_or_create method.

**I need to create a record only on sign up page with my required params, otherwise, on the sign in page, I just need check if the user already signed up and redirect to sign up page if necessary.**

Am I clear?

**Model:**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    def self.from_omniauth(auth)
        where(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid).first_or_create do |user|
            user.email = auth.info.email
            user.password = Devise.friendly_token[0,20]
            user.name = auth.info.name
            user.avatar = auth.info.picture
            user.username = auth.info.name.parameterize.dasherize.first(10) + Digest::SHA2.hexdigest("#{Time.now.utc}").first(5)
            user.skip_confirmation!
        end
    end
end
```

**Callback:**

```
class Users::OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController
    def facebook
        @user = User.from_omniauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"])

        params = request.env["omniauth.params"]
        @user.username = params["username"]
        @user.newsletter = params["newsletter"]
        @user.diet_id = params["diet_id"]

        if @user.persisted?
            sign_in_and_redirect @user, event: :authentication
            set_flash_message(:notice, :success, kind: "Facebook") if is_navigational_format?
        else
            session["devise.facebook_data"] = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
            redirect_to new_user_registration_url
        end
    end

    def failure
        redirect_to root_path
    end
end
```

**Relevant code for signup page:**

```
= form_tag user_facebook_omniauth_authorize_path(newsletter: @user.newsletter, username: @user.username, diet_id: @user.diet_id) do
```

**Relevant code for sign in page:**

```
= link_to "Sign in with Facebook", user_facebook_omniauth_authorize_path
```

Comment: I'm having this exact issue. did you ever resolve it?

Comment: any luck on this one?